# The Rules And Tricks Use To Find The Equivalent Resistance

Tags: circuit-design, resistance

To find the equivalent resistance we use different tricks and rules to simplify the circuits. But I have confused on the basics of using those techniques.

I breifly searched in google to find the common techniques which can use to simplify a complex circuit but I can't understand how do those techniques not differ the initial circuit.

A Common technique is folding the circuit on a vertical or horizontal line;
`

[image]

- **But what is the basic of folding it on that line?**
- **What are the requirements for folding the circuit for simplify?  and**
  **
- **How is it not differ the initial circuit after folding on that line?**

**

I expect a theoretical answer. If you can add an example and describe it. it will more beneficial.

Comment: I have never heard of bending a circuit on a line. Can you [edit] to give an example?

Comment: Sorry, but "coinciding" isn't a word we would use either. We will need an example of we are to help you.

Comment: @Transistor I have add more to my question after editing

Comment: There is no general method other than to look for resistors in series and parallel that can be combined to simplify the circuit.  Also look for symmetries that can also simplify the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the basic of folding it on that line?

The rule is simple. If the circuit is symmetrical then we can fold on the line of symmetry. In the original circuit the voltages on each of the mirrored node pairs would be identical so we can use one set of resistors but at twice the current so half the resistance (R/2).

Note that the resistors on the axis of symmetry did not change their value.

> What are the requirements for folding the circuit for simplify?

Only that it is symmetrical.

> How is it not differ the initial circuit after folding on that line?

It *is* different but it *is* **equivalent**. Internally you have changed the circuit but when looked at from the outside (the left wire and right wire) you can't tell the difference. If you measured the resistance between the two outer terminals it is the same in both cases.